# Two Player Number Guessing Game - Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a game where Player One picks a number and Player Two has 5 Guesses to guess it. If he manages to do so, he wins, if not, he losses and Player One wins.

So I have the code, but if for example Player one picks the number '3' and Player Two enters the number '3' on any of his goes, it still says Player One wins.

```
>>> 
Player One enter you chosen number: 3
Player Two have a guess: 3
Player One wins.
>>>
```

This happens also:

```
>>> 
Player One enter you chosen number: 5
Player Two wins.
```

Also, player two can have as many turns as he likes, but it should only be 5. If he passes that amount, Player One automatically wins. Here is my code: (I don't know here I went wrong.)

```
def Game():
    Guess = 0
    NumberOfGuesses = 0
    NumberToGuess = int(input("Player One enter you chosen number: "))
    while NumberToGuess < 1 or NumberToGuess > 10:
        NumberToGuess = int(input("Not a valid choice, please enter another number: "))
    while Guess != NumberToGuess and NumberOfGuesses < 5:
        Guess = int(input("Player Two have a guess: "))
        NumberOfGuesses = NumberOfGuesses + 1
    if Guess == NumberToGuess:
        print("Player One wins.")
    else:
        print("Player Two wins.")


Game()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if statement is the wrong way around.
Instead of

```
if Guess == NumberToGuess:
    print("Player One wins.")
else:
    print("Player Two wins.")
```

it should be

```
if Guess == NumberToGuess:
    print("Player Two wins.")
else:
    print("Player One wins.")
```

because player 2 wins if he guesses the number that player 1 has chosen (NumberToGuess).
I cannot reconstruct your second problem where player 2 wins immediately of player 1 enters 5. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The logic is wrong. If the input is not equal to `NumberToGuess` then you cannot print `Player Two wins.`

You must then loop. Then outside the loop check if player one was successful.

```
while Guess != NumberToGuess and NumberOfGuesses < 5:
    Guess = int(input("Player Two have a guess: "))
    NumberOfGuesses = NumberOfGuesses + 1
    if Guess == NumberToGuess:
        print("Player Two wins.")

if Guess != NumberToGuess:
      print("Player One wins.")
```

Comment: Yes I agree. Still print that player 2 wins even if he does not get the guesses...

Comment: @Filip How?? I don't think so

Answer (score 0):

```
"""This game generates random number, then players try to guess the number generated"""

import random
#generate number directly
num = random.randrange(1,5)

#initialize global variables
player1 = "Human"
player2 = "Alien"
player = ""
player1PlayCount = 0
player2PlayCount = 0
maxPlayTimes = 3

#game logic
def Game():
    global player1, player2, player, player1PlayCount, player2PlayCount, maxPlayTimes, num
    """enter and assign names to players"""
    player1Name = input('Player1 Enter Your Name: ')
    player2Name = input('Player2 Enter Your Name: ')
    
    player1 = player1Name
    
    player2 = player2Name
    
    player = player1
    
    print(player1, 'turn')
    
    while ((player1PlayCount and player2PlayCount) != maxPlayTimes):
        guessNum = int(input("Guess Number: "))

        if guessNum == num:
            print(player, "won")
            exit()
            
        elif player == player1:
            player1PlayCount +=1
            player = player2
            print(player2, 'turn')
            
        elif player == player2:
            player2PlayCount +=1
            player = player1
            print(player1, 'turn')

        else:
            print("Both ", player1, " and ", player2, " lose")
            exit()
Game()
```